# What is best way to select multiple html tags and their value to apply expression in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, html-table

I have a specialized e-commerce cart I built  where the customer selects how many of rooms, floors, etc. from a table and then it calculates the value live.

Html table entries for each drop down option looks like this

```
<table>
    <td><select onchange="calculateall()" id="roomsclear1" size="1">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
       <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>  </td>
</table>

 <h1> Total:<h1> <p id="total"> Final Value goes here after calculation of all 20 options</p>
```

Each type of cleaning service unfortunately has a different price point so  I tried this switch statement.

```
var selectedt = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

function calculateall() {
  for (var i = 0; i < selectedt.length; ++i) { 
         var calcit = selectedt.options[selectedt[i].selectedIndex].value;
         var typeid = selectedt[i].id;

         switch (typeid) {
                case 'roomsclean1':
                calcit = calcit * 65;
                break;
            }
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = calcit;
        }
}
```

Questions:

1. I'm only getting a 0 or 1 value written to total in HTML no matter what option I select from the table. I assume I'm screwing up on the Javascript.
2. Is a switch statement the most efficient option? 20+ options each with different pricing per # of rooms selected

I put an example of the cart on a temporary page here(slow!):

52.11.14.57:9000/#

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mvc1poad/

The ID in the example correspondes to carpet cleaning tabs: rooms(clean)

Comment: Could you output the actual values to your inputs? Or, do you plan to define the price in your JavaScript and just multiply? Also, you will have multiple selects?

Comment: Yes, multiple selects; this page(slow loading!) has the table I'm working on: http://52.11.14.57:9000/#/. I could output the actual values if I  match a specific element by id and remove the switch statement; I assume I'm making a mistake in javascript.

Comment: I edited my answer, but here's an updated fiddle based on what you created: https://jsfiddle.net/mvc1poad/1/ (instead of a switch statement, I'm just pulling the values from a `data-attr` of the select element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Rakesh_Kumar is correct, the issue is the lack of `parseInt`. Adding that should address the issue when calculating values.

You mentioned you can output the actual values (which I'd recommend since it will simplify your script slightly). Personally, I would wrap an element around your `select` element(s) and allow a `change` event to `bubble` up (rather than an inline event handler like `calculateall` - just cleans up your HTML).

Something like:

```
<form id="ourForm">
    <select id="cleaning">
        <option value="0">Select cleaning</option>
        <option value="0">No cleaning</option>
        <option value="10">Cleaning final day only</option>
        <option value="50">Cleaning 5 days</option>
    </select>
    <!-- additional elements here -->
</form>
```

And a simple JS `event listener` like this:

```
document.forms[0].addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var i = 0,
        query = this.querySelectorAll('select'),
        len = query.length,
        total = 0;
    for(; i < len; i++) {
        if (parseInt(query[i].value, 10) > 0) {
            total += parseInt(query[i].options[query[i].selectedIndex].value, 10);    
        }
    }
    // Do something with total here
}, true);
```

Here's a demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sj9o6Lnb/

If you're interested in using a multiplier, you could create a `map` which you then multiply the values by. Something like:

```
var price_map {
    rooms_clean: 65,
    breakfast: 100
}
```

Which you then reference the price by an id (or some other attribute)

```
for(; i < len; i++) {
    total += price_map[query[i].id] * parseInt(query[i].options[query[i].selectedIndex].value, 10);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sj9o6Lnb/1/

Here's an updated fiddle based on your site (with the four options and clean/protect): http://jsfiddle.net/sj9o6Lnb/2/

And an edited fiddle that you created: https://jsfiddle.net/mvc1poad/1/ (this one here just calculates based on a data attribute, which you would need to add)

Answer (score 0):

You have made a silly mistake, because of which you are not getting expected output.
Instead of doing like:

```
//selectedt is HTMLCollection having list of all elements with tag "select"
//& typeof calcit is String, which you need to make a number before multiplying with 65
var calcit = selectedt.options[selectedt[i].selectedIndex].value;
```

do,

```
var calcit = parseInt(selectedt[i].options[selectedt[i].selectedIndex].value);
```

And, apart from switch usage, what other approach you are thinking to take. For Obvious reasons, `switch` is more preferable than `if-else`.

Comment: I'm still getting a 0 final value.

Comment: Strange; It only returns the first on-change value but not *65 and afterwards it will not chance again. It works in the fiddle but not my website.....

Comment: can you make a fiddle and share...that will be better to check.

Comment: your `calculateall` function itself is not getting triggered at first point..You need to remove function definition within `window.onload`

Comment: I've tried both html onchange and javascript's event handler but it still isn't working. This is an AngularJS site so perhaps that's the reason?

Comment: @udonsoup16 I have made some changes & updated your fiddle..Let me know if that helps.. https://jsfiddle.net/mvc1poad/2/

Comment: still doesn't change, unfortunately.